# Can Collada (dae) be used as content?

Tags: c#, xna, collada

Can the Collada (dae) file format be used for content, or is it strictly for reciprocity between 3D studios, etc? For example, I create a XNA game, could I create a loader and load it in for usage in my game? Would it be wise and legal to do this? Or can I only use it to transfer between Maya and 3D Max?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collada is a perfectly acceptable format to use with XNA.  Benjamin Nitschke has created an excellent tutorial on loading a Skinned Collada model with all of the necessary loader classes etc. on his [website](http://abi.exdream.com/Blog/post/2007/02/25/Skeletal-Bone-Animation-and-Skinning-with-Collada-Models-in-XNA.aspx).  The source code is at the end of the article along with some other useful links.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely use it as the main format for your game.

Many systems support directly loading COLLADA:

- [Second Life Mesh](http://wiki.secondlife.com/wiki/Mesh)
- [Ogre](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/Ogre+COLLADA+Plugin)
- [GLGE](http://www.glge.org/collada-now-supported/)
- [three.js](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_collada.html)

and many more.

If you're using C#, there is a [C# Collada library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/csharpcollada/).

Comment: This library looks helpful. I will take a look.